# Create a list of years with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column of dates of the form

```
2004-01-01
2005-01-01
2006-01-01
2007-01-01
2008-01-01
2009-01-01
2010-01-01
2011-01-01
2012-01-01
2013-01-01
2014-01-01
2015-01-01
2016-01-01
2017-01-01
2018-01-01
2019-01-01
```

Given an integer number k, let's say k=5, I would like to generate an array of the next k years after the maximum date of the column. The output should look like:

```
2020-01-01
2021-01-01
2022-01-01
2023-01-01
2024-01-01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use `pd.to_datetime` + `max` to compute the largest date in the column `date` then use `pd.date_range` to generate the dates based on the offset frequency one year and having the number of periods equals to `k=5`:

```
strt, offs = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).max(), pd.DateOffset(years=1)
dates = pd.date_range(strt + offs, freq=offs, periods=k).strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()
```

---

```
print(dates)

['2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2024-01-01']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
# this is your k
k = 5
# Creating a test DF
array = {'dt': ['2018-01-01', '2019-01-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
# Extracting column of year
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dt']).year
year1 = df['year'].max()
# creating a new DF and populating it with k years
years_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (1,k+1):
    row = {'dates':[str(year1 + i) + '-01-01']}
    years_df = years_df.append(pd.DataFrame(row))
years_df
```

The output:

```
dates
2020-01-01
2021-01-01
2022-01-01
2023-01-01
2024-01-01
```